# semaphore not waiting for second time function call for web service in ios

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore

I have class with multiple function. In that class two functions I have called web service, the first web service function works proper. But second web service method not waiting for response from the service it can automatically call another service 
I have Used

```
let saveSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0) as dispatch_semaphore_t
let count = arrDeleteExecutionDetails.count

for (index, object) in arrDeleteExecutionDetails.enumerate()
{
    Common.checklistExecute = object

    let request = "\(Common.webServiceURL!)/ProInspectorJson.svc/DeleteExecutionDetails?pExecutionDetailsId=\(object.id_ExecutionDetails!)"
    let webservice = WebServiceCall(url: request, delegate: self)

    webservice.webServiceGetMethod(request)

    if index != count-1
    {
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
    }
    else
    {
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
    }
```

The above method working properly

```
for checklistExecution in arrExecutionDetails
{
    Common.checklistExecute = checklistExecution

    let request = "\(Common.webServiceURL!)/ProInspectorJson.svc/SaveExecutionV3?scheduleID=\(checklistExecution.id_Agendamentor!)&userID=\(Common.userId!)&ID_PI_ChecklistConfiguration=\(checklistExecution.id_ChecklistConfig!)&Observations=\(checklistExecution.observation!)&ID_PI_tblMastRiskFactor=\(checklistExecution.id_RiskFactor!)&CorrectiveAction=\(checklistExecution.correctiveActions!)&ID_PI_FormulaResultsHeader=0&Longitude=0&Lattitude=0&checklistExecutionId=\(checklistExecution.id_ExecutionDetails!)&ErrorCode=0&ID_PI_ObjectSubCategory=\(checklistExecution.objectSubCategory!)"

    let webservice = WebServiceCall(url: request, delegate: self)

    webservice.webServiceGetMethod(request)

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

}
```

But the second one not working

`for` loop have 5 element, the 5 elements called simultaneously. It is not waiting for first service response.

```
dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
```

I have called perfectly.

Comment: You don't want to use a semaphore for this. Use a dispatch group instead. That's the proper solution when you need to wait for a group of processes to complete.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example does not perform `dispatch_semaphore_wait` on the last iteration of the loop, but rather it curiously issues yet another `dispatch_semaphore_signal`. Assuming your delegate always issues a signal, you'll end up with a mismatch of semaphore signals.

As a result, if you use the same semaphore in the second example, you'll likely end up with two extra signals (not only the signal you issued in your `for` loop in your first example when `index` was `count - 1`, but presumably your last iteration of the delegate method also likely issued an unsatisfied signal), and thus three requests in your second loop will run concurrently.

When you use this semaphore pattern, make sure each "signal" is matched by a "wait". If you add `print` statements at each "signal" and "wait", these sorts of unbalanced calls will jump out at you (rather than seeing alternating "wait" and "signal" calls, you'll see a series of "signal" calls in succession (in this case, at the end of the first `for` loop)).

Bottom line, you likely want to remove the `if index == count-1 { ... }` check, and just `dispatch_semaphore_wait`. If there's something weird going on in the delegate methods that requires some logic here, you should edit your question showing us why you employed the logic you did.

Even better, you really should excise your code of these semaphores altogether, and instead embrace asynchronous patterns. Writing synchronous code feels so intuitive, but it actually is inefficient (blocking threads; losing huge benefit of concurrent requests; etc.) and problematic (susceptible to deadlocking; should never be done from main thread; etc.). You should embrace asynchronous patterns such as dispatch groups or `NSOperation` dependencies.